# What is the conterpart of the WCF in Java or any other platforms?

Tags: java, wcf, rest, service

What is the conterpart of the WCF in Java or any other platforms? What is the newest buzz word to write something like WCF service in Java?

I know Spring MVC can be used to create Rest services, but what is considered the best practice to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289977/recommended-framework-for-java-web-services